# nested directives - link and controller function not executes in child

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm sure that I'm missing some part.
i have nested directives as follows and the child link and controller functions not executed when file loaded.

my index.html file is:

```
<champ-table>
    <champ-column></champ-column>
    <champ-column></champ-column>
    <champ-column></champ-column>
    <champ-column></champ-column>
</champ-table>
```

in this for the cham-column is not getting compiled. but when the file is like this:

```
<champ-column></champ-column>
<champ-column></champ-column>
<champ-column></champ-column>
<champ-column></champ-column>
```

the link function and the controller function log the string to console.

here are my directives: champ-column

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('champ').directive('champColumn',function(){
        return {
            restrict : 'E',
            controller : function(){
                console.log('champ-column controller loaded');
            },
            link : function(scope,element,attrs){
                console.log('champ-column linked');
            }
        };
    });
})();
```

and champ-table

```
(function(){
    angular.module('champ').directive('champTable',function(){
        return {
            restrict : 'E',
            scope: {
                table : '='
            },
            templateUrl : './app/directives/champTable/champ-table.tpl.html',
            link : function(scope,element,attrs){
                some code here...
            }
        };
    });
})();
```

have searched for a while in the Web for solutions but saw only examples with structure similar to mine that work. So it must be something I've done wrong or missed. Needless to say that I'm including the scripts file in the index file of course. 
tried to remove the scope in father element, and did not help. please if you have idea it would be great! thank you!

Comment: please provide your html: did you write something like: <tag ng-app="champ"></tag>

Comment: I guess the template of `<champ-table>` is overwritting the internal `<champ-column>`s. Add `transclude: true` in the definition of `<champ-table>`, and `<div ng-transclude></div>` in its template, where the children are supposed to go.

Comment: before you debug the `directives` further, you may want to fix this: `angular.module('champ')` to include an empty array if there are no dependencies: `angular.module('champ', [])`

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos dude that worked for me like magic. finally I know why the hell I need this terrible 'transclude' phrase.

Comment: @ShehryarAbbasi I use an instance of app I created in other file. sorry for not mention this.